# Entity Relational Diagram: Link professors to departments

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have entity types Professors and Departments.
Could you please give me some hints on how to realize the following:

- Professors work in one or more departments.
- Departments have a chairman.
- The chairman of a del. should work in that department.

I have difficulty with the part: The chairman of a del. should work in that department.

Comment: There is definitly more then one way to realize this, but why don't add a column `ChairmanID` to the department, which points to a professor?

Comment: Yes, We can do it, but question is, whether it is one of the prof who actually work in that department. This would be a relationship (is a chairman of)  like this: profs. -- (0,1)--- (is a chairman of) -- (1,1) --- departments.

Answer (score 0):

You have two tables. One is staff, the other is department.

Staff can be either professor or chairman. It is decided by one column "position"

Staff and department has many-to-many (professiors to department) as well as many-to-one (dean to department)

The chairman can only work on that department. So you will need to remember to get chairman when you try to get all the professors.

Comment: Also you will need an extra column, which stores chairman id in department.